# MySQL is returning a different value then the max value in the sample code provided

Tags: mysql, sql, max

In the playertracker table, I want the result to display the deck name associated to the row that has the highest value where the player id (PID) is equal to a given value. Instead a the first deck name is returned along with the largest amount.

```
create table players(
  pid int(10),
  pname varchar(20),
  favcard varChar(20),
  mstplayed varChar(20),
  lestplayed varChar(20)
  );

 create table playertracker(
  pid int(10),
  deckName varchar(20),
  amount int(10)
  );

 Insert into players
   values(1, 'joe', 'swim', 'jump', 'fall'),(2, 'jane', 'up', 'jump', 'fall'),(3, 'jack', 'up', 'jump', 'fall'),
   (4, 'joe', 'up', 'all', '5'),(5, 'joe', 'up', 'red', 'fall');

 Insert into playertracker
   values('1','jump','2'),('1','up','4'),('1','swim','9'),('1','fall','9'),
   ('2','jump','8'),('2','up','4'),('2','swim','1'),('2','fall','1'),
   ('3','jump','1'),('3','up','8'),('3','swim','9'),('3','fall','4'),
   ('4','jump','9'),('4','up','8'),('4','swim','1'),('4','fall','1'),
   ('5','jump','1'),('5','up','4'),('5','swim','4'),('5','fall','8'),
   ('6','jump','4'),('6','up','9'),('6','swim','1'),('6','fall','1');


   select deckname, max(amount) from playertracker where pid = 1;
```

[Link to the offending SQL](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a439ce/3)

Comment: Link seems to be broken...

Comment: Hey, I believe it is still working. I just tried it there

Comment: @bloopiebloopie Link isn't broken. Its working

Comment: I'm just getting a 404 - still right now...

Comment: Your `group by` usage is invalid. Instead of throwing an error like every other DBMS, MySQL chooses to return random data instead. http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/09/06/wrong-group-by-makes-your-queries-fragile/

Comment: I am not using a group by statement though!

Comment: Long story short, your query is invalid SQL. MySQL accepts it but the values it returns for column `deckname` are [indeterminate](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html). Other RDBMSes reject it. And yes, you are using an implicit `GROUP BY` due to the usage of a [`GROUP BY` aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html)

Comment: Excelent, axiac! On reading a_horse_with_no_names comment and the article they provided (cheers for that article horse), I thought that max() implicitly called a group by but I was unsure. Thank you for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is query but return two row

```
select deckname, amount from playertracker where pid = 1
 and amount = (select max(amount) from playertracker where pid = 1) ;
```

because

```
swim    9
fall    9
```

so

```
select deckname, amount from playertracker where pid = 1
 and amount = (select max(amount) from playertracker where pid = 1)
 limit 1 ;
```

Comment: Limit 1, and your laughing. I don't understand why the other statement was not working though.

Comment: I just warned you that your query of two results

Comment: Because select column1, max(column2) return the firts colum1 value and not the value of the row there is the max .. well if my answer is right please mark as accepted .,.

Comment: I didn't ask a question. Thanks though, I will mark it as right. I was trying to understand why the provided example did not return the max name. I think the answer I was looking for was given by @a_horse_with_no_name. Though I still don't get it fully; the statement dose not include a group by clause. All I can imagine is that max() implicitly groups stuff. Is this the case, do you thing? Sorry about my poor English and again thanks for your help.

Comment: In your sqlfiddle i don't see any group by so i don't know what mean a_horse_with_no_name,  Well in your  case adding a group by with your condition  pid =1 can't solve the question (or is unuseful) then you need to find the the row with the value equal to max .. and this is not provided by group by .. in this case the subselect or a join is  the right solution .. .. Anyway in mysql a improper use of group by is not signed like an error but relturn only a wrong result .. be carefull for this  .. i hope this explanation is useful..

Comment: Thank you very much @scaisEdge

Answer (score 0):

```
select deckname, max(amount) from playertracker where pid = 1 group by deckname;
```

Comment: Hi, this returns all the decks belonging to this user. I could "orderby" and "limit 1" to get max and min values, I just thought that there must be a more elegant way.

Comment: Your response would be more helpful if you explained how / why it resolves the problem.